# What are intermediate values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, variables

First of all, I'm a beginner in Python. Therefore, I'm sorry if my question seems ridiculous for you. I'm, currently, reading a book on Python, its author has mentioned temporary variables, and says that they are variables used to hold intermediate value, therefore, what are intermediate values?

For example:

```
def print_message(name):
    message = 'Hello, ' + name + '!'
    return message
```

message is a temporary variable.

Comment: What book?​​​​​ Please give us some context.

Comment: @vaultah It's "Think Python: How to Think Like A Computer Scientist"

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from your question, when coding algorithms to calculate mathematical formulas it often takes many intermediate (or in-between) steps. During these steps is when you compute several intermediate values. When debugging, you can save these intermediate values in temporary variables to check if the values the computer has calculated are correct.

From the edit that you made, you give message as the intermediate value which would mean the local variables of the functions are intermediate. These passed in values as well as local variables are destroyed when the function has finished executing. It would be called intermediate by the author since it is only exists in the scope of the function, and is destroyed when the function exists.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like they are not meaning that in any technical way. Just a variable that's used to help you compute what you are after. Like if you want to compute the average of numbers in a list, you might first create a variable to hold the sum. It's not what you really are after, but it's an intermediate value.